# How can I view my logged in desktop on Red Hat with my VNCViewer?

Tags: redhat, vnc

I have TigerVNC running on my Red Hat machine.  I am using 5902 and 5903.  When I remote in, it is a whole new X session.  I changed one of the ports to 0, but RH says it is already being used.  I am trying to see the currently logged in person's session.

I cannot connect to port zero, 5900.  I get connection refused.  I am logged in as root on the server machine.  I am connecting from a Windows machine if that matters.

I want to be able to remote in and see who is currently logged in on the Linux machine and what is going on, like I can a Windows machine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ive fought the same issue.You want [x11vnc](https://www.google.com/search?q=x11vnc) .

It'll let you see a logged in X display just like you describe. Ive used it where I was logged in on a linux desktop, walked away and then was remote and wanted to pick back up where I left off. You just ssh into the system start x11vnc and then you can see your display.

Edit to add that theres a bit of a gotcha if you arent logged in and the workstation. If the workstation is at a login screen, itll still work but you have to do a bit more work to get the thing going. [more details on that here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229989/how-to-setup-x11vnc-to-access-with-graphical-login-screen)